# Splunk API not working with cURL using port 8000

Tags: bash, curl, authentication, splunk

I'm trying to login on my local Splunk server using curl bash command but without success, so far I have tried the following:

```
curl -u admin:changeme -k http://192.168.1.103:8000/en-US/account/login
curl -u admin:changeme -k http://192.168.1.103:8000/en-US/account/login -d"username=admin&password=changeme"
```

Any help would be very appreciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to do REST calls? You need to hit port 8089

Comment: So it's impossible to get a valid reply from HTTP on port 8000 instead of 8089 for authenticating with curl ? on port 8089 i can get:

<sessionKey>30774f9d502004b5c655c08b5362bdca</sessionKey>

but... best would be to get a valid HTTP response on port 8000 since port 8000 is authorized on the network and almost all other ports (like 8089) is blocked.

Comment: @Gerald Clearly you aren't traversing subnets through a blocked firewall since you got the response on port 8089.  Not sure of what your concerns are with continuing to do so, but if you want to change the port, see here: https://answers.splunk.com/answers/293929/is-it-possible-to-change-the-current-port-8089-of.html along with it's fair warnings about doing so